Is there a name for equivalence classes with just one element?
Assume I have some equivalence relationship defined on a set. Is there a generally accepted name for those elements of the set that have no other members except themselves in their equivalence class? Or perhaps for those equivalence classes that only have one element?

I would call them “the singleton classes”

Maybe "trivial classes"

Thank you. But how generally accepted is this term? Do I need to define it on first use or can I assume that an average mathematician understands it?

Also, can I refer to the member forming this class as a singleton or only to the equivalence class itself?

I think the term singleton is correct, for example it is used in P. R. Halmos, Naive Set Theory (p. 28) in this context. See the citation on this page: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3238622/equivalence-classes-of-elements-in-x-vs-equivalence-class-of-x-times-x

When in doubt, include a brief definition.

By all means! Or has paper and ink become unaffordable?
